# Plotting variables from a list

Tags: netlogo

I am trying to plot the velocity distribution of the turtles in my model. The velocity vector vi of each turtle is contained in a list (coordinates vix, viy) I am not sure if using

```
plot max item 0 [vi] of turtles
```

is showing what I really want which is the maximum velocity of all turtles. I wonder if max-one-of primitive would be better? but when I use

```
plot max-one-of turtles item 0 [vi]
```

of course, I received the error *expected a literal value*. As it is a list I do not know how to rewrite item 0 [vi] to be recognized by the plot.

What I am doing now is creating a monitor using max-one-of as I think this will do what I want

```
max-one-of adults [item 0 vi]
```

but the monitor is showing me (adult 24) and it's okay, I have checked that from all turtles in the simulation for that particular tick, adult 24 has the higher velocity but I want the monitor to show me the velocity value (number) not the who number. How can I do this?

I guess after making the monitor do what I want I can copy that piece of code into the plot to create the graph.

I thank you in advance for your thought and recommendations =)!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If I understand the question correctly, then this should do the trick:

```
plot max [item 0 vi] of turtles
```

If you were to write this with `max-one-of`, it would come out as:

```
let winner max-one-of turtles [item 0 vi]
plot [item 0 vi] of winner
```

but as you can see, `max-one-of` isn't really helping.

Comment: Thank you Seth, actually, your suggestion helped a lot. I think now I am on a much better track to achieve what I want. My plot is showing what I expected =)